# looking to connect my ionic 4 project with pouchdb. But keep getting error 'can't access lexical declaration'

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I keep on getting 'can't access lexical declaration' error when i try to access this page but it works fine when i comment pouch db statements.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-newperson',
  templateUrl: './newperson.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newperson.page.scss'],
})
export class NewpersonPage implements OnInit {

  private name;
  private email;
  private phone;
  private db;

  constructor(
    private router : Router
  ) {
    // this.setupDB();
  }

  setupDB() {
    this.db = new PouchDB('contacts');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(PouchDB);
    
    this.setupDB();
    this.name = 'John Doe';
  }

  goBack() {
    this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
  }

  save() {
    // this.db.post({
    //   name: this.name,
    //   email: this.email,
    //   phone: this.phone
    // })
    console.log('save clicked');
    
  }

}
```

My primary goal at this stage is just getting started with pouchdb. Also the youtube video link :-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWbsN1QIIN8&t=1693s

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure.  Did you add pouchdb to your ionic project package.json?  In my projects db is defined as an any.

private db: any;